# How to import XML from drive to Google Sheet

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets, import

I was searching through stackoverflow since some days but non of this solution worked for me.

I just want to import an XML from Drive to Google Sheet.

Meanwhile I am aware that it doesn't work through simple function using importxml or importdata.

If the file is stored in Drive, then we need the ID

[XML File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sRmSdXh46wo8yoHOy4kdoBYkeg1dc1Zw/view?usp=drive_link)

[I also saved the XML into text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZKZN-2_uCcOwRAxdH0xwW9ZqhtkV0ItB/view?usp=drive_link)

Everyone with the link can view the files.

At this point I figured out that we need to use App script.

Isn't there a way to import the whole XML?
And isn't there a way to import all  or  from the XML or Text file?
If someone could show me or point me into the right direction for example how to import all"Book"-divs from the XML or TXT, then I might be able to figure out the rest.

Best
Alan

I tried Importdata and ImportXML function which did not work.

I tried all approach from StackOverflow where others created a script in APPScript but non of them worked.

I googled a lot but non of the approach works. I am always been told to move the file to another cloud server but it needs to be from google drive

Best
Alan

Edit: this one works but not for all XML.

```
    function xmlParser() {
const fileId = "1sRmSdXh46wo8yoHOy4kdoBYkeg1dc1Zw";
const data = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
let document = XmlService.parse(data); //have the XML service parse the document
let root = document.getRootElement(); //get the root element of the document
let foods = root.getChildren("book"); //gets the list of books in the catalog
let list = [] //we create an array that will hold the data
foods.forEach(function (food) {
fields = food.getChildren()
subList = []
fields.forEach(function (field) {
subList.push(field.getText())
})
list.push(subList)
})
writeToSheet(list)
}
function writeToSheet(list) {
let range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, list.length, list[0].length)
range.setValues(list)
}
```

For one of my XML I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

writeToSheet    @ Untitled.gs:19

xmlParser   @ Untitled.gs:16

Answer (score 0):

The very basic script below shows a start point:

```
function getXML() {
  const FILE_ID = '1sRmSdXh46wo8yoHOy4kdoBYkeg1dc1Zw';
  var s = DriveApp.getFileById(FILE_ID).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  Logger.log(s);
  var xml = XmlService.parse(s);
  var ids = xml.getRootElement().getChildren().map(
    function(bookElement) {
      var book_id = bookElement.getAttribute('id').getValue();
      var genre = bookElement.getChild('genre').getText();
      Logger.log(book_id);
      return [book_id, genre];
    }
  );
  // Write book identifiers to the active sheet's A:B columns
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, ids.length, 2).setValues(ids);
}
```

It uses [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app?hl=en) to access to the file content and [XMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service?hl=en) to parse it.

Comment: Thank you! This helps as well to understand it. Let's assume I would like only the content of the element <genre>...</genre> to be displayed, How would I do this? Or do I need a workaround for this?

Comment: ok, "genre" is included in the code.

Comment: Ah, now I got it! Thanks a lot. Just a quick question. If I for example use "catalog", i get this error

 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getText')

I am trying to understand why I get this error? I get the same error if I use book or book id="bk101". Is it because it still has some child elements?

Comment: It is not "quick" for explaining. There are different methods for reading XML elements (nodes), root element, attributes, etc.  I can't see your code errors, but I can suggest useful [introduction to XML](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_tree.asp). Also pay attention to the links in my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about the following patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `IMPORTXML` is used. From `Everyone with the link can view the files.`, I confirmed that your file has already been publicly shared. In this case, the values can be retrieved by `IMPORTXML` using Drive API with an API key.

In this pattern, the XML file is required to be publicly shared. Please be careful about this.

It seems that your URL is like `https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileId}/view?usp=drive_link`. In this case, the URL is changed to `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{fileId}?alt=media&key={yourAPIKey}`. Please use your API key.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1sRmSdXh46wo8yoHOy4kdoBYkeg1dc1Zw?alt=media&key={please replace this with your API key}","//*[local-name()='book']")
```

When this formula is used using my API key, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Google Apps Script is used.

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and please set your sheet name and file ID. In this sample script, your file ID is used. And, please save the script.

In this pattern, the XML file is not required to be publicly shared.

```js
function sample() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const fileId = "1sRmSdXh46wo8yoHOy4kdoBYkeg1dc1Zw"; // or "1ZKZN-2_uCcOwRAxdH0xwW9ZqhtkV0ItB" Please set file ID of the XML file or the text file including XML data.

  // Parse XML data and create an array.
  const str = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const xml = XmlService.parse(str);
  const books = xml.getRootElement().getChildren();
  const header = books[0].getChildren().map(c => c.getName());
  const values = [header, ...books.map(b => b.getChildren().map(c => c.getValue()))];

  // Put values into a sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

When this script is run, your XML data is retrieved from the XML file and put into the sheet. And, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided XML data. When you change the XML data, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Method: files.get of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)
- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for taking yoyr time to help me.

I tried this on another XML and I get this message now:
Exception: Your input contains more than the maximum of 50000 characters in a single cell.

So I can assume that there is a limit when it comes to cell characters.

Edit: I am aware that if I change the XML it might not work but according to your code it should still work since we did not call any specific element from the XML to import it

Comment: @Here2Learn Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that at least, your showing XML data is different from your tested XML data. And, the reason for your current issue is due to the size of the XML data. In that case, it is required to use Google Apps Script. But, unfortunately, I cannot find the result of my proposed script in your reply. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Here2Learn By the way, I cannot understand `Edit: I am aware that if I change the XML it might not work but according to your code it should still work since we did not call any specific element from the XML to import it `, can I ask you about the detail of it? I deeply apologize for my poor English skill.